# How to echo a specific content after fetching 4 rows in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, fetch, backend, grid-system

I am making a backend system, and the displayed product from the index page should follow the grid system. For example, I have 8 products from MySql database. I want to divide them into 2 rows, 4 products each. So my PHP code would look like:

```
<div class="row">
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<div class="col-dsk-4"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

As you can see in the code, I want after echoing 4 times (4 times `<div class="col-dsk-4">`), the while loop exits, then continues a new `<div class="row">` until it loops through all the element in the MySql Table.

Is my solution correct or not? If so, please help me, else, please show me your solution.

Comment: Hi, @ChingChongPa, can you point out in details please? I am not sure if I get it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See my answer below, you were kind of close, but my answer should show you how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below.

What I'm doing is instead of using `while` I've switched it to a `foreach` to go through the array.

I'm using `count` to dictate when the `<div class="row">` should be added.
On the first item and every 4th item, it should add a new row.

I've also updated the way I'm calling `<?php ?>` so it's easier/cleaner to read.

If you have any questions let me know:

```
<?php $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products"); ?>
<?php $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result); ?>

<!-- Use count to decide when to put a new div with class 'row' -->
<?php $count = 1; ?>

<?php foreach ($rows as $key => $row) { ?>

    <!-- Create a new div with class 'row' on the first item + everytime theres a 4th one -->
    <?php if ($count == 1 || ($count % 4 == 0)) { ?>
        <div class="row">
    <?php } ?>

        <div class="col-dsk-4">
            <?php echo $row["name"]; ?>    
        </div>

    <!-- Close div with class 'row' everytime theres a 4th one -->
    <?php if ($count == 1 || ($count % 4 == 0)) { ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <!-- Increment the count -->
    <?php $count++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Oh, that what I need, thanks a lot for helping me figure this out.

Comment: however, instead of increasing the count, you can set it back to 0 whenever count is larger than 4

Comment: Yep that's another way of doing it

Comment: Hi @giolliano sulit, after a long time testing and figure out myself, I found out your code has some bugs that need to be fixed: The first thing is about array $rows. You have to do a while loop to insert value into it first, after that you can do a foreach loop. Also, I found a solution for while loop, using the same method you told me. Anyway, thanks for your support!